# SQL index for date range query

Tags: sql, database, indexing, sql-server-2014, database-performance

For a few days, I've been struggling with improving the performance of my database and there are some issues that I'm still kind a confused about regarding indexing in a SQL Server database.

I'll try to be as informative as I can.

My database currently contains about 100k rows and will keep growing, therfore I'm trying to find a way to make it work faster.

I'm also writing to this table, so if you suggestion will drastically reduce the writing time please let me know.

Overall goal is to select all rows with a specific names that are in a date range.

That will usually be to select over 3,000 rows out of a lot lol ...

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[reports]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IsDuplicate] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsNotValid] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ShortDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](350) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](350) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.reports] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is the SQL query I'm using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [db].[dbo].[reports]
WHERE Source = 'name1' 
  AND ShortDate BETWEEN '2017-10-13' AND '2017-10-15'
```

As I understood, my best approach to improve efficency without hurting the writing time as much would be to create a nonclustered index on the `Source` and `ShortDate`.

Which I did like such, index schema:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Source&Time] 
ON [dbo].[reports]([Source] ASC, [ShortDate] ASC)
```

Now we are getting to the tricky part which got me completely lost, the index above sometimes works, sometime half works and sometime doesn't work at all....

(not sure if it matters but currently 90% of the database rows has the same Source, although this won't stay like that for long)

1. With the query below, the index isn't used at all, I'm using SQL Server 2014 and in the Execution Plan it says it only uses the clustered index scan:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM [db].[dbo].[reports]
   WHERE Source = 'name1' 
     AND ShortDate BETWEEN '2017-10-10' AND '2017-10-15'
   ```
2. With this query, the index isn't used at all, although I'm getting a suggestion from SQL Server to create an index with the date first and source second... I read that the index should be made by the order the query is? Also it says to include all the columns Im selecting, is that a must?... again I read that I should include in the index only the columns I'm searching.

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM [db].[dbo].[reports]
   WHERE Source = 'name1' 
     AND ShortDate = '2017-10-13'
   ```

   SQL Server index suggestion -

   ```
   /* The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following 
      index could improve the query cost by 86.2728%. */

   /*
   USE [db]
   GO

   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
   ON [dbo].[reports] ([ShortDate], [Source])
   INCLUDE ([id], [IsDuplicate], [IsNotValid], [Time], [Email])
   GO
   */
   ```

Now I tried using the index SQL Server suggested me to make and it works, seems like it uses 100% of the nonclustered index using both the queries above.

I tried to use this index but deleting the included columns and it doesn't work... seems like I must include in the index all the columns I'm selecting?

BTW it also work when using the index I made if I include all the columns.

To summarize: seems like the order of the index didn't matter, as it worked both when creating `Source + ShortDate` and `ShortDate + Source`

But for some reason its a must to include all the columns... (which will drastically affect the writing to this table?)

Thanks a lot for reading, My goal is to understand why this stuff happens and what I should do otherwise (not just the solution as I'll need to apply it on other projects as well ).

Cheers :)

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. This is a product specific question.

Comment: Added the tag sql-server-2014. ty

Comment: Is it necessary to use `SELECT *`? https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-code-smells/#using-select-in-a-batch

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Indexing in SQL Server is part know-how from long experience (and many hours of frustration), and part black magic. Don't beat yourself up over that too much - that's what a place like SO is ideal for - lots of brains, lots of experience from many hours of optimizing, that you can tap into.

> > I read that the index should be made by the order the query is?

If you read this - it is absolutely **NOT TRUE** - the order of the columns *is* relevant - but in a different way: a compound index (made up from multiple columns) will only ever be considered if you specify the **n left-most columns** in the index definition in your query.

Classic example: a phone book with an index on (city, lastname, firstname). Such an index *might be used*:

- in a query that specifies all three columns in its `WHERE` clause
- in a query that uses `city` and `lastname` (find all "Miller" in "Detroit")
- or in a query that only filters by city

but it can **NEVER EVER** be used if you want to search only for `firstname` ..... **that's** the trick about compound indexes you need to be aware of. But if you always use all columns from an index, their ordering is typically not really relevant - the query optimizer will handle this for you.

---

As for the **included columns** - those are stored **only** in the leaf level of the nonclustered index - they are **NOT** part of the search structure of the index, and you cannot specify filter values for those included columns in your `WHERE` clause.

The main benefit of these included columns is this: if you search in a nonclustered index, and in the end, you actually find the value you're looking for - what do you have available at that point? The nonclustered index will store the columns in the non-clustered index definition (`ShortDate` and `Source`), and it will store the **clustering key** (if you have one - and you **should!**) - but nothing else.

So in this case, once a match is found, and your query wants **everything** from that table, SQL Server has to do what is called a **Key lookup** (often also referred to as a *bookmark lookup*) in which it takes the clustered key and then does a **Seek** operation against the clustered index, to get to the actual data page that contains all the values you're looking for.

If you have **included columns** in your index, then the leaf level page of your **non-clustered** index contains

- the columns as defined in the nonclustered index
- the clustering key column(s)
- **all those additional columns** as defined in your `INCLUDE` statement

If those columns "cover" your query, e.g. provide all the values that your query needs, then SQL Server is done once it finds the value you searched for in the nonclustered index - it can take all the values it needs from that leaf-level page of the nonclustered index, and it **does NOT need** to do another (expensive) key lookup into the clustering index to get the actual values.

Because of this, trying to always **explicitly specify** only those columns you *really need* in your `SELECT` can be beneficial - in this case, you *might be able* to create an efficient **covering index** that provides all the values for your `SELECT` - always using `SELECT *` makes that really hard or next to impossible.....

Comment: First of all thanks for correcting my mistakes and this informative answer!  
After reading your comment 3 time I can say with confident that I understand alot better how indexes works.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that the reason my index isn't used when I'm not including the columns is that because it find thousands of rows, and then needs to do a key lookup for all those rows to get all the non-included columns it just not as efficient.

Comment: For now I believe that *covering index* would be my best approach as I'm not searching for a specific row but alot in the same query.
because that columns I include are few and not large in size I hope it won't take as much space... although still not completely sure how bad will it affect the insert to the table.

again thanks alot for you comment @marc_s :)

Comment: @Ben: exactly - if you find *too many hits* in a non-clustered index, then the cost of doing thousands of key lookups into the clustered index can be prohibitive - so that the query optimizer just switches to a clustered index scan instead.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you want the index to be from most selective (i.e. filtering out the most possible records) to least selective; if a column has low cardinality, the query optimizer may ignore it.

That makes intuitive sense - if you have a phone book, and you're looking for people called "smith", with the initial "A", you want to start with searching for "smith" first, and then the "A"s, rather than all people whose initial is "A" and then filter out those called "Smith". After all, the odds are that one in 26 people have the initial "A".

So, in your example, I guess you have a wide range of values in short date - so that's the first column the query optimizer is trying to filter out. You say you have few different values in "source", so the query optimizer may decide to ignore it; in that case, the second column in that index is no use either.

The order of where clauses in the index is irrelevant - you can swap them round and achieve the exact same results, so the query optimizer ignores them.

EDIT:

So, yes, make the index. Imagine you have a pile of cards to sort - in your first run, you want to remove as many cards as possible. Assuming it's all evenly spread - if you have 1000 separate short_dates over a million rows, that means you end up with 1000 items if your first run starts on short_date; if you sort by source, you have 100000 rows.

Comment: I see, 
For my use, over millions rows I'll probably have up to 10 different sources.
and the ShortDates could be over 1000.
then how should I make the index? maybe only for the date? 
Thanks Neville

Comment: also if thats the case, why does it use the index if I include all the columns? @Neville

Answer (score 0):

The included columns of an index is for the columns you are selecting.
Due to the fact that you do `select *` (which isn't good practice), the index won't be used, because it would have to lookup the whole table to get the values for the columns.

For your scenario, I would drop the default clustered index (if there is one) and create a new clustered index with the following statement:

```
USE [db]
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_reports
    ON [dbo].[reports] ([ShortDate],[Source])
GO
```

Comment: it does not make a sense to include columns into a clustered index

Comment: You are right :) I just copied his suggested index.
Now I have removed the included columns.

Comment: Wasn't aware that "select *" is bad practice, I changed it although it isn't the reason the index isn't used.
wouldn't a clustered index reduce the writing time by alot?
If I'm searching by the source first, should the index made as ([Source],[ShortDate]) ?
ty

Comment: The clustered index is the order in which the data is stored in the physical file. So you always have one.
The order of the columns in the index definition doesn't matter.

Comment: This is probably a bad idea - the clustered index affects the sequence in which records are stored in the database, and if you have records out of sequence, it will have to re-shuffle the entire table on insert or update.

Comment: Imagine that you use `select *` in a client application and bind a value to the second column for example.
Later, however, you add an additional column as first column for that table. Your code will crash and you will need some time to find out why.

Comment: @Neville: It depends on the ratio of inserting and selecting data. Due to the fact that the table is named 'reports', I assume that the select performance is more important than the insert performance.

Comment: That is not correct :), 
The reports used by us, therfore we could survive if it won't be the most optimise.
trying to find the right balance , with that knowledge will you still do the index you suggested?

Comment: I would try it. 100k rows isn't really much for a SQL server and if you are not inserting thousands of rows per minute, I don't think that the index will impact the insert performance.

Comment: [It's not about the star](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-08/its-not-about-the-star-stupid)